# SQL CE private deployment on a machine with central deployment

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, clr

I am trying to run an application with SQLCE. The machine which I am running on has sql ce 3.5 installed. However, the application uses version 4.0+.
When the application runs on the machine, it throws the known exception:

```
Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to 
the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL 
Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details..
```

This, although I have the amd64 and x86 folders in the location of the ADO provider (System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll).
After reading microsoft docs at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg213826(v=sql.110).aspx under the section of: Updates and Private Deployment, I realized that the CLR probably loads the old sql ce version.

However, I don't know how to make him load the private deploy assembly, as I am not sure I have understand their tips to address this issue.

Some constraints: I can't uninstall the sql ce 3.5 on the machine.
I cant install the newer version with central deployment.

Someone got a trick ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EF or raw ADO.NET ? The CLR will never load 4.0 instead of 3.5 as they have different assembly version unless you have a binding redirect.

If you use EF with SQL CE 4.0, you can use my "private deployment" package https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.PrivateDeployment/

If you use raw ADO.NET or LINQ to SQL, see my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html